# Can I implement in my Express js application both JWT authentication and Google authentication?

Tags: express, authentication, jwt, google-oauth

I have created one simple application with React and Express where authentication is required and it is based on JWTs, every time user logs is, server sends him a new access token (by the way, in this jwt access token payload I store only user ID, which is number generated by MySQL when user was first registered, I don't know, maybe I have to handle it any other way?) so I also want my application to support google authentication, but I do not know how can I do that, if my server verify users credentials by this jwt access token which contains user id from database. As far as I know, when user logs in via google account, a new secret id is generated for this user, which is string, so how can I handle both my custom authentication and google authentication in one app?  How am I supposed to store those users in database? And what about firebase? I have read some information about client side authentication using firebase, but how does it work? How does server deal with such kind of authentication? I'll appreciate any help!

Comment: @HeikoTheißen Thanks! It really gave me some answers, but I have one more question, as I said, I store user's id in jwt payload to have an access to all other tables in database that uses user's id as a foreign key, so how can google's jwt contain the same id? Or, generally speaking, what is stored in this google jwt payload and how can I verify who this user is? Sorry if I sound too ignorant, but I just try to understand the whole process, thanks in advance!

Comment: Google's JWT contains the email address, I suggest that you use that as the user's id.